# Why does GraphiQL not show the "data" property, but just the "errors" property for Subscriptions?

Tags: graphql, rxjs, apollo-client, graphiql, apollo-angular

When executing a Subscription via Graph*i*QL (v 1.5.1) which throws an error, but also contains data, why doesn´t Graph*i*QL show the data? And how to achieve this?

In the following screenshot it can be seen that the payload of the websocket message contains both errors and data as properties:
[image: GraphiQL Network Tab]

Nevertheless, the data from "data" will not be displayed on the Graph*i*QL interface:
[image: GraphiQL interface]

The problem occurs only for Subscriptions and not for Queries.